# Probability of dividing $2$ aces to $2$ players from a total of $2n$ cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is an exercise from Ross' A First Course in Probability.

A total of $2n$ cards, of which $2$ are aces, are to be randomly divided among two players, with each player receiving $n$ cards. Each player is then to declare, in sequence, whether he or she has received any aces. What is the conditional probability that the second player has no aces, given that the first player declares in the affirmative?

This is part of the solution given in the text.

If $A_i$ is the event that player $i$ receives an ace, then 
$$P(A_i)=1-\frac{\binom{2n-2}{n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{n-1}{2n-1}=\frac{3n-1}{4n-2}$$By arbitrarily numbering the aces and noting that the player who does not receive ace number one will receive $n$ of the remaining $2n-1$ cards, we see that 
$$P(A_1A_2)=\frac{n}{2n-1}$$

I don't understand the last reasoning. Why do we get the probability that both players receive an ace $n$ divided by $2n-1$?

Answer (score 1):

"Why is the probability that both players receive an ace equal to $\frac{n}{2n-1}$?"

Exactly as it suggests, temporarily assume that the aces are distinct, say for example one is the ace of spades and the other is the ace of hearts.

First, look at who receives the ace of spades.  Now... wherever the ace of spades happened to be in that players deck, each other position in each players decks is equally likely to be each remaining card.  Even more specifically, the ace of hearts is equally likely to occur in each remaining position in each deck.

As there are $n$ positions available in the "other player's" deck (*other player here meaning the player who did not receive the ace of spades*) and each of those positions were equally likely to be the ace of hearts out of the $2n-1$ equally likely positions that could have been occupied by the ace of hearts (*$2n-1$ here instead of $2n$ because remember the ace of hearts cannot occupy the same position as the ace of spades*) the probability then is $\frac{n}{2n-1}$